# Noise on DC voltage LTspice

Tags: noise, ltspice, simulation, spice, voltage-source

Is there a way to add noise to a DC voltage source in LTspice?
I'm trying to simulate a DC/DC converter and want to know how the circuit responds to a ripple/noise on the input. I.e. +/-100mV noise/ripple on a 15V DC source.

Comment: No a DC voltage source is just that: DC, meaning no variations over time. Like an (ideal) battery. For voltages that change over time, use a vpulse or vpwl. You **can** use a vdc and a vpulse in series if you prefer. That would simply sum the voltages.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a DC source in series with a ripple source and a noise source. The latter is a behavioral voltage source which can be found under components as *bv*. The advantage of separating B1 and V1 is that you can also assign an AC voltage to V1, so it will work in *.ac* analyses.

[image]

Comment: `V1` and `V2` can be combined into a single one, with the appropriate offset.

Comment: yup, you are right, @concernedcitizen I was wondering if the operation point for ac analyses would be calculated properly without a simple DC source.

Comment: The op point is calculated based on the initial value of the source. If it represents the DC then confetti.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to low pass filter your DC source and high pass filter in your AC (noise) source like this:

[image]

The inductor and capacitor needs to be sufficiently large for your load in question.

Comment: I would simply put V2 (sine) and V1 (DC) in series to get the same voltage across R1

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ah yes, even easier!

Comment: You can also just use an AC source with a DC offset if you want the ripple to be a sinusoid.

Comment: I ended up using a behavioral voltage source with a value of V=15+(white(2e6*time)/5)

Comment: @Jaap Many solutions to choose between!

Comment: You could do it the easy way: a single `SIN({DC} {peak_ripple} {freq})`.

Comment: @aconceredcitizen Yes, that works too.